# How to access the last-yanked text programmatically?

Tags: yank, kill-ring, defun

How can I use the last thing yanked in a command I'm writing?

For example, if the last text I yanked was `"test"` I want to use this string somehow in my command.

(I use `avy` and `evil`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last thing you yanked is typically the front of the `kill-ring`.

You can access that programmatically as `(current-kill 0 'DONT-MOVE)`.

For example:

```lisp
(defun my-command ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (message "The current kill string is: %s" (current-kill 0 'DONT-MOVE)))
```

Then you can do `M-x my-command` to yank what you last yanked.

Actually, the current kill is not necessarily what you last yanked. It's what you last yanked, killed, or copied to the `kill-ring`, whichever of those actions is most recent. And it's what your *next* yank would yank (by default).

---

(I think using Avy and Evil are irrelevant to what you're asking, so I removed those tags.)

(Your question as originally worded spoke of using the latest yank as an "argument" of the command or other function you're writing. It's not clear how you want to do that - from what you want to pass it to your function as an argument. But the idea is the same: you access the latest kill using function `current-kill`.)

(Your question as originally worded spoke of "interactive function", so I included `interactive` in the answer. Dunno if that's what you're really looking for.)